# How to avoid unnecessary shuffle in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-shuffle

I have two CSVs. `df_sales`, `df_products`. I want use pyspark to:

1. Join `df_sales` and `df_products` on `product_id`. `df_merged = df_sales.join(df_products,df_sales.product_id==df_products.product_id,"inner")`
2. Compute the summation of `df_sales.num_pieces_sold` per product. `df_sales.groupby("product_id").agg(sum("num_pieces_sold"))`

Both 1 and 2 would require the `df_sales` to be shuffled on `product_id`

How can I avoid shuffling `df_sales` 2 times?

Comment: Why you don't want it shuffle ?

Comment: If you grouped the df resulting from the join I wouldn't expect a second shuffle. Perhaps this doesn't meet your need?

Comment: @AmirHosseinShahdaei - I do not want it shuffled twice

Comment: @Chris - After join I would apply a filter as well which would get optimized as the first operation and would be applied on the map side itself. So it wont be the same thing

Comment: Sounds like you have two actions. I would expect`persist`ing `df_merged` would avoid a second shuffle and prevent filter from being optimized as the first transformation.

Comment: if `df_products` is considerably smaller, you coud broadcast it while joining

Comment: THis is a classic https://xyproblem.info/ you aren't telling us the issues just asking for help answer to a solution you have chosen.  Could you explain the problem?

Comment: Have you enabled adaptive query? `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled",true)`

Comment: @samkart That is handled automatically by Spark.

Comment: @Chris that is a good suggestion. Will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to do what you ask would be to use `repartition` to shuffle the dataframe once, and then `cache` to keep the result in memory:

```py
cached_df_sales = df_sales.repartition("product_id").cache()

# and then do your work
cached_df_sales\
    .join(df_products,cached_df_sales.product_id==df_products.product_id,"inner")
cached_df_sales.groupby("product_id").agg(sum("num_pieces_sold"))
```

However, I am not sure this is a good idea. Depending on its size, caching the entire `df_sales` dataframe might take a lot of memory. Also, the `groupBy` will only shuffle two columns of the dataframe, which could turn out to be rather inexpensive. I would start by making sure of that before trying to avoid a shuffle.

More generally, before trying to optimize anything, write it simply, run it, see what takes time and focus on that.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I actually had tried caching the repartitioned data but it ended up being significantly slower than not caching it. I had read it somewhere that the output of a shuffle operation is always persisted on the reduce side and used in case it can be used later on. I wonder why that is not happening in my example